# Convert XYZ coordinates to coordinates along profile using arbitrary coordinates

Tags: shapely

This is a seismic-related question. I have the surface trace of a 2D seismic line as LineString (XYZ coordinates). In addition, I have the interpretation of a horizon as XYZ coordinates along the line as LineString. The aim is now to convert the 3D coordinates of the horizon into the position along the line measured in CPDs (Common depth points, start and end points of CDPs known, regular spacing).

I have used the following code to complete the task. It is working but it is very inefficient. Maybe someone has an idea how to speed things up.

1. Function to explode LineString to single elements (LineStrings consisting of two vertices)

```py
def explode_linestring_to_elements(linestring: shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString):
    return list(map(shapely.geometry.LineString, zip(linestring.coords[:-1], linestring.coords[1:])))
```

2. Exploding LineString

```py
list_segments = explode_linestring_to_elements(line)
```

3. Getting the fractional position along the seismic line (wrapped in `calculate_position_on_seismic_one_point()`)

```py
# Calculating the distance of the point to each segment
distances_to_segments = [line.distance(point) for line in list_linestrings]

# Getting the index of the smallest value
index_min = distances_to_segments.index(min(distances_to_segments))

# Calculating the distance to the start of the line segment
distance_to_start = shapely.geometry.Point(list(list_linestrings[index_min].coords)[0]).distance(point)

# Calculating the distance from the start of the seismic line to the point
distance_to_point = sum([line.length for line in list_linestrings[:index_min]]) + distance_to_start

# Calculating the fraction of the seismic line
fraction_of_line = distance_to_point / shapely.ops.linemerge(shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(list_linestrings)).length
```

4. Getting the position along the seismic line

```py
position = (fraction_of_line * (cdp_end - cdp_start)) + cdp_start
```

5. Using List comprehension to get the positions of all picked vertices of the horizon. (features is a GeoDataFrame containing the interpreted horizon

```py
# Calculating CDP position along seismic for features
features['X_CDP'] = [calculate_position_on_seismic_one_point(list_linestrings=list_segments,
                                                                 point=shapely.geometry.Point(
                                                                     (features.loc[i]['X'], features.loc[i]['Y'])),
                                                                 cdp_start=cdp_start,
                                                                 cdp_end=cdp_end) for i in tqdm(range(len(features)))]
```

Step 5 and the underlying function is the part that needs to be optimized. Let me know if anythin is unclear and I am looking forward to some suggestions :)